# How placing script tags before </body> improves the page loading performance

Tags: javascript, html

I need to load lot of libraries on the html pages in my project.But I came across through many sources that placing the script tag before the closing the body tag improves the loading performance.If it is true,I would like to the concept behind this.

Thanks in advance,
Krish

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser doesn't know if your script changes the DOM structure, so it blocks the rendering of the page if it encounters a `<script>` tag. By placing the script tags at the bottom, the browser can render the whole page, so the content is shown earlier to the user.

Comment: Thanks Daniel that explains it.But my application is little different.This uses Galio browser(not html5 supported) and it loads some 10 sub applications in a loop  and then show the home page at once.It takes around 2 mins to load all the sub apps.I thought placing scrips at the end will help in loading all the sub apps faster.But this does nt help it in my case.

Comment: Did you consider showing each subapp as they are finished loading? This way your time to screen would be reduced.